# Python GDAL JPEG Library

Tags: python, gdal

In Anaconda Python I am getting the following error:
`0ERROR 1: JPEGLib:Wrong JPEG library version: library is 62, caller expects 80`
I am running Ubuntu 14.04. I found a few references to this problem, but no fix.

Comment: So why not install a newer version, like the error tells you?